# dexOptions is specifying a maximum number of 24 concurrent dx processes, but the Gradle daemon was initialized with 4

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have server with 24 cores and 64G of memory. A want to launch gradle build with 24 concurrent dx processes. I have such options:

**build.gradle**

```
dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048m"
        maxProcessCount 24
    }
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.workers.max=24
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx12G

android.compile.sdk.version=25
android.build.tools.version=25.0.2
android.gradle.plugin.version=2.3.0
```

I am using gradle 3.3 via gradle wrapper.
I am using such command for build.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest
```

I have such strings in the output:

```
dexOptions is specifying a maximum number of 24 concurrent dx processes, 
but the Gradle daemon was initialized with 4.
To initialize with a different maximum value, 
first stop the Gradle daemon by calling ‘gradlew —-stop’.
```

**gradlew --stop** is not helping . Launch with disabled daemon also not helping.
I have found this code [android-gradle-plugin sources](https://github.com/zawn/android-gradle-plugin/blob/master/builder/src/com/android/builder/core/AndroidBuilder.java#L1421) but do not figured out how to use it.

Comment: did you find what was the problem?